# Configure GRE via Netplan (headless/aws)

Tags: networking, 18.04, netplan, tunnel

How to translate the below to a Netplan yaml file with networkd as the renderer?

At the command line these commands work and build a GRE tunnel with an MTU of 1476.

```
ip tunnel add gre1 mode gre remote [x.x.x.x] local [y.y.y.y] ttl 255
ip link set gre1 up
ip addr add [z.z.z.z]/30 dev gre1
```

Where [x.x.x.x] is the remote GRE endpoint, [y.y.y.y] is the private IP of GRE endpoint and [z.z.z.z] is the address assigned to the local GRE interface.

Tried using the following yaml fragment the tunnel is defined but MTU is 'ignored' and the LAN i/f MTU-24 is set.

```
    tunnels:
        gre1:
            mode: gre
            local: [y.y.y.y]
            remote: [x.x.x.x]
            mtu: 1476
            addresses:
                - [z.z.z.z]/30
```

The output from various commands:

```
# systemctl status systemd-networkd | grep gre1
Sep 16 11:49:40 ip-y-y-y-y systemd-networkd[1283]: gre1: Cannot enable IPv6 for interface gre1: No such file or directory
Sep 16 11:49:40 ip-y-y-y-y systemd-networkd[1283]: gre1: Could not bring up interface: Address family not supported by protocol

# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9001 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 16:74:7e:e0:07:46 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet [y.y.y.y]/24 brd [y.y.y.255] scope global dynamic ens5
       valid_lft 2631sec preferred_lft 2631sec
    inet6 fe80::1474:7eff:fee0:746/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: gre0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1476 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/gre 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
4: gretap0@NONE: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1462 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: erspan0@NONE: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1450 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: gre1@NONE: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP> mtu 8977 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/gre [y.y.y.y] peer [x.x.x.x]
    inet [z.z.z.z]/30 brd [z.z.z.255] scope global gre1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Answer (score 0):

:embarrassed:
The yaml fragment in the question is effective after a system restart, Just running 'netplan apply' wasn't enough.